# How to connect database in UnitTestCase subclass?

Tags: 8, testing

I know there are mockups, data providers, bla bla bla.
I don't care now, I just want to connect to my dev site db and use nodes, terms for unit tests.

How can I do it? In D7 it was very simple in plain PHPUnit, what about D8?

I've tried bootstrap D8, but failed.

Comment: Have you reviewed https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/testing/8.2.x ?

Comment: @Kevin so I should use WebTestBase to access/create nodes in tests?

Comment: anyone? So I MUST use this slow like lava hell simpletest again?

Comment: This totally defeats the purpose of a unit tests. You should be creating an integration test or higher level test. Drupal 8 supports thats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See https://www.drupal.org/phpunit for better documentation.

There are 4 test base classes:

- UnitTestBase, pure unit tests where everything but your code has to be mocked and only supports classes
- KernelTestBase, which provide a basic in-memory drupal environment. Much faster than browser tests but more tedious to set up, you have to explicitly install tables you need and depend on all modules you need explicitly
- BrowserTestBase, the replacement for WebTestBase, better apis (uses mink and so on) but just as slow.
- JavaScriptTestBase, phantomjs based JS tests, even slower but can actually execute JS.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose that I can replace BrowserTestBase & JavaScriptTestBase with Behat testing, right?

Comment: Yes, you can implement external testing with Behat. Using it will not create an isolated install of Drupal, which means tests will execute faster. Be sure to grab the Drupal Behat Extension. Here is a small writeup demonstrating it. https://www.velir.com/blog/2016/08/25/behavior-driven-testing-drupal-8

Comment: Just as extra note... I have been able to setup Behat/Drupal Behat/DrupalVM and the SeleniumHQ Docker stack. It is worth it.

Comment: @Kevin thanks, could you point me to more details about Behat + SelecniumHQ Docker integration?

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for is Kernel Test base. You can already create nodes and terms there if you want to, and it still can be fast (3-6 seconds).

In Unit test you only test your class and mock the rest, you can't really make real entity instances.

Comment: yea, but If I need to test something related to custom fields I need to create them also in code and if there is a lot of dependencies it becomes tedious task. I mean perspective from working with a lot of legacy code.

Comment: I agree on this. You will need to make a decision, if you would like to use the faster kernel tests, with much more setup at the beginning, or using the much slower webcase test, where you already got almost everything you need! In most cases I still go for Kernel tests, but this is my taste.